# Why does `clang-format --version` return 1

Tags: bash, command-line, rhel, clang

I'm working on a RHEL7 and I just installed `clang`: `sudo yum install clang`.

Then I execute the command `clang-format --version` and the output is below:

```
me@localhost:~$ clang-format --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.4.2
  Optimized build.
  Built May 10 2018 (10:48:27).
  Default target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: x86-64

me@localhost:~$ echo $?
1
```

As you see, `clang-format --version` seems to work without any error but `echo $?` shows me a `1`.

What's wrong with this command?

I just did the same thing on an Ubuntu system and there is no such an error.

The output of `type -a clang-format`:

```
clang-format is /usr/bin/clang-format
clang-format is /bin/clang-format
```

The output of `file "$(command -v clang-format)"`:

```
/usr/bin/clang-format: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=899595580dbae12ee1ae6eb9feb8a19aa6d51f49, stripped
```

Comment: What do `type -a clang-format` and `file "$(command -v clang-format)"` show?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  I re-edited the the post.

Comment: ok, I thought that clang-format on RHEL is a wrapper but it's not. What version of clang-format are you using on Ubuntu? There were some changes in reporting version https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140106/096564.html

Comment: On Ubuntu, the version of `clang-format` is 3.8.0. On RHEL, it's 3.4.2.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with release 8.0.1 on OpenBSD.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I can reproduce with sglim2/centos7 docker image after installing
`clang 3.4.2` as OP said they did. I think that version reporting has
been changed in clang-format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be reproduced with older versions of clang-format
available for install with `yum` in `sglim2/centos7` docker image for
example.  `clang-format --version` has been modified to return 0 in
[this
commit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/02b958422c0b6177eb693f55544ecfeebe55d210):

> CommandLine: Exit successfully for -version and -help
>
> Tools that use the CommandLine library currently exit with an error
>   when invoked with -version or -help. This is unusual and non-standard,
>   so we'll fix them to exit successfully instead.
>
> I don't expect that anyone relies on the current behaviour, so this
>   should be a fairly safe change.
>
> llvm-svn: 202530